# Как сделать второй экран для вывода принтов Kivy

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy

Нyжно ,что бы при нажатие на кнопкy '`Start`' приложение переходило на второй экран и выводило 'Hi'

`Main.py`:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
    
    
    class Scr1(BoxLayout):
        def Hi(self):
            While True:
                print('Hi')
    
    class Scr2():
        pass
    
    class MyApp(App):
    
        def build(self):
            box = BoxLayout()
            button1 = Button(text="start")
            box.add_widget(button1)
            return box
    
    if __name__ == "__main__":
        MyApp().run()
```

`.kv`:

```
<Scr1>
    Button:
        size: 100,30
        text: "start"
        on_press:
            root.Hi()
```

Answer (score 1):

print('Hi') и вывод слова "Hi" в окне - это абсолютно разные процессы, не имеющие ничего общего.

Чтобы в стартовом окне создать кнопку "start" - не нужно делать двойную работу. Либо в файле *.py через функцию и команду add_widget, либо прямо в файле *.kv

Ну и в файле *.kv создать еще один виджет, который и будет тем самым заветным окном с текстом "Hi".

Рабочий пример программы из двух файлов ниже

Файл Main.py

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
    

class ScreenManager(ScreenManager):
    pass
    
class Scr1(Screen):
    pass
    
class Scr2(Screen):
    pass

kv = Builder.load_file("My.kv")

    
class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return kv
    
MyApp().run()
```

Файл My.kv

```
ScreenManager:
    Scr1:
    Scr2:


<Scr1>:
    name: "scr1"

    BoxLayout:
        Button:
            size: 100,30
            text: "start"
            on_press: root.manager.current = 'scr2'



    <Scr2>
        name: "scr2"
    
        BoxLayout:
            Label:
                text: "Hi"
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]